# Updated the M2E extension via Magento Connect and now I receive blank pages

Tags: magento-enterprise, extensions, m2e, ebay

I noticed Magento was kind enough to remind me that I need to update the M2E Ebay Store Extension. I did so through Magento Connect and now I get nothing but blank pages on both the front end and admin end of the site so I'm stuck with blank pages and not sure what to do. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Make sure to flush the whole cache storage and try again. If you still see white page, check php error log and let us know what errors are being logged there.

Comment: What I ended up doing was I commented out, in the config.php file, define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH',dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src'); and define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH',dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat'); This ended up fixing my problem and I was able to get the site back up and going. Many many thanks for your input though!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ang, in comment you confirmed solution which worked for you, I would like to sum this up. It looks you might forgot to disable compilation before you installed new extension.

You should remember to always disable compilation before you install any extension. Disabling all caches for the time you are installing extension could also be good idea and help in a few cases.

You can disable compilation in  `System -> Tools -> Compilation` by using `Disable`  button.

Comment: And actually, don't enable compilation again. It's not useful enough to justify the hassle you get from it.

Comment: You're right, I did forget to mention about disabling compilation. I'm with fschmengler, I've already had it disabled because I too believe it's not useful enough.